# What's the best way to retrieve the position of an element relative to one of its ancestors?

Tags: jquery

I have a td inside a table.

What's the best way to get its position relative to the table?

Should I be using offset, position or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

```
var tablePos = $("#myTable").offset();
var tdPos = $("#myTable td:first").offset();

var relativePos = {};
relativePos.top = tdPos.top - tablePos.top;
relativePos.left = tdPos.left - tablePos.left;
```

You would obviously use your own selectors to get the appropriate table object and td object, I just used examples here.